# Erlang sytax error with 'Or'

Tags: erlang

I got this very newb and simple function in erlang:

```
function_x(L) ->
    X = lists:filter((fun(N)-> N =:= 2 end), L),
    Y = lists:filter((fun(N)-> N =:= 3 end), L),
    LX = length(X),
    LY = length(Y),
    LX == 2 or LY == 2.
```

Compile the source, and I get this error:

```
syntax error before: '=='
```

I pull of one of the expressions from the or clausule and it works. I'm very newb in erlang as you see and really don't understand why this happens if it seems so simple. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [operator precedence in Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id201628), the precedence of `or` is higher than that of `==`. So your expression as written is treated as

```
LX == (2 or LY) == 2
```

which is a syntax error. To fix this, you must use parentheses around each term:

```
(LX == 2) or (LY == 2).
```

Alternatively, you can use `orelse` which has a *lower* precedence than `==`:

```
LX == 2 orelse LY == 2.
```

Comment: Thanks! I was loosing my faith in erlang heh :D

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, == and 'or' probably have the same operator precedence, so you need to tell the compiler more exactly what it is you want. You could either write "(LX == 2) or (LY == 2)" or use 'orelse' instead of 'or'.

Comment: Nah, `or` has a higher precedence than `==` so the expression is parsed as `LX == (2 or LY) == 2`, but as `==` has no associativy, this results in a parse error.

Comment: I'd use `orelse` here. It is short-circuiting and it is probably a tad faster. Also, there is no reason to evaluate the RHS for the effect.

Comment: The fact that the comparison operators aren't associative surprised even me, but of course, it's not the thing you'd write in any sane program, so they might be better off without.